# Arch Linux setup Luks encryption

Tags: luks

So I'm trying to encrypt a partition sda2 while installing Arch Linux.

```
root@archiso ~ # cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda2 -c aes-xts-plain -y -v -s 512 -h sha512
```

But it fails:

```
Cannot format device /dev/sda2 which is still in use.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `lsof` to see what is using the device...

Comment: I can't run `lsof` on that machine.

Comment: @Kaotic Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's in use, you should check whether it's mounted, loop-device'd, still cryptsetup-opened, active in LVM, part of a RAID set, etc. and then stop all these things. Also quit any running processes that might be using the device (partitioners, installers, ddrescue, badblocks, ...). The list of possibilities as to what could be using a device, is nearly endless. `lsof` or `fuser` are able to catch some of them...

```
# example only, none of these are accurate
umount /dev/sda2
losetup -D
vgchange -a n
cat /proc/mdstat | grep -C 2 sda2
mdadm --stop /dev/md??
...
```

Or, if you want to deliberately ignore the issue, you could explicitely put a loop device on top and then format the loop device. You should reboot afterwards to see if whatever was still using the device, would corrupt your LUKS header because of it (if you can't open it after reboot, that's what happened). Without rebooting, you might be able to copy data happily on the device but it's all gone later...

```
# dangerous hack
cryptsetup luksFormat $(losetup --find --show /dev/sda2) -s 512 -h sha512 ...
reboot
```

Also triple-check that you're actually working with the correct device in the first place. In your post you somehow mentioned both sda1 and sda2 so which is it?

This is not part of your issue, but `aes-xts-plain` is deprecated in favour of `aes-xts-plain64`. It's also the default cipher so you don't have to specify it at all. (see `cryptsetup --help` or luksDump afterwards.)

Comment: It's sda2 but sda1 should work aswell because it's going to be the boot partition. I tried your examples but they didn't solve the issue. How do I use `lsof` if my installation of arch isnt done yet?

Comment: Encrypting the boot partition isn't such a great idea.

Comment: Well thats true but it should do the encryption which it isnt. Just mistyped sda1. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Got it. You were right it the container was still open. Thanks alot.